# Update multi query by multiple instances of a service leads to deadlock in mysql

Tags: mysql, multi-query

I have a service that runs an update multi query `update hits set hits = hits + 1 where id = x`.
I found out that running multiple instances of this service throws error `Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.

I don't know why this is happening or how to debug this. There's only one row being updated at a time which should not lead to deadlock. Does multi query acquire lock for all the columns at once? will the query below acquire lock for all x, y, z rows?

```
update hits set hits = hits + 1 where id = x; update hits set hits = hits + 1 where id = y; update hits set hits = hits + 1 where id = z;
```

Comment: can you share SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

Comment: @NikhilB this is production database for our company I don't think can share it here. I am new to all this so I am not sure which data I can share and which I can't.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959592/mysql-deadlock-error

Comment: @NikhilB Thank you, will look into this, might help